# copying array of object to another array using java

Tags: java, arrays

I am trying to copy my instrumentalist array into a new array called copy array and when I go to run it, it just goes blank after I am done the do while loop and doesn't print out the musicians names I have entered. from what I can find  and know already I thought this is the right way to copy an array to another. thank you in advanced for your personal input

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Scanner keyboard= new Scanner(System.in);
        final int MAXPEOPLE=100;
        instrumentalist [] instrumentalistArr;
        instrumentalistArr=new instrumentalist[MAXPEOPLE];
        char choice;
        int index=0;
        int instrumentalistCOUNT=0;
        do {
            instrumentalist ainstrumentalist = new instrumentalist();
            ainstrumentalist.readin();
            instrumentalistArr[index]=ainstrumentalist;
            instrumentalistCOUNT++;
            index++;
            System.out.println("would you like to enter another data set yes or no");
            choice=keyboard.next().charAt(0); 
        } while(choice!='n');

        instrumentalist [] copyarray;
        copyarray=new instrumentalist[instrumentalistArr.length];

        for(int i=0; i<instrumentalistCOUNT; i++) {
            copyarray[i]=instrumentalistArr[i];
        }

        for(int i=0; index<instrumentalistCOUNT; i++) {
            System.out.println("musician"+" "+ copyarray[index].getmusicianname());
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In this for loop:

```
  for(int i=0; index<instrumentalistCOUNT; i++)
{
    System.out.println("musician"+" "+ copyarray[index].getmusicianname());
}
```

Change `index` to `i`.

So your for loop should be:

```
for(int i=0; i<instrumentalistCOUNT; i++)
{
    System.out.println("musician"+" "+ copyarray[i].getmusicianname());
}
```

Comment: oh wow i feel dumb, totally forgot to switch my variables when i made my copyarray thanks so much!